# The package prefix is missing in directory tree -- how to handle it with Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, directory-tree

*I downloaded some Java program sources, and I try to import them to Eclipse.*

Let's say I have package with name "com.bar.foo.my", and the directory is set like this:

```
src/bar/foo/bar/my
```

so sources have their distinct directory but level "com" is missing.

**Question:** How can I set Eclipse so it would understand this "shortcut"?

### Updates:

At the top level the program consists of such directories:

```
assets
bin
gen
libs
out
res
src
```

I am showing them to indicate it is not just bunch of *.java files put in the `src`.

Comment: what does your java files have as their package name: `bar.foo.my` or `com.bar.foo.my`?

Comment: You are asking what I see in *.java source files? `com.bar.foo.my`.

Answer (score 1):

Easy, create a Java project, have the "src" directory be the source folder in your Java build path (this will probably be the default), if not look/change it using Build Path -> Configure Build Path on the project menu.

Then import them into your workspace somewhere (using Import -> Files into workspace) and then create a "com" package under your src folder.

Finally, move the "bar" folder to the "com" package (just drag/drop in the Package/Project explorer).

(You can't have the "com" folder missing as that violates the Java assumption that the classloaders depend on that the file hierarchy much match the package name exactly.)

Comment: tl;dr: You can't, your "shortcut" is simply not valid.

Comment: I am new to Eclipse but something tells me that in effect I will get quite different structure. It would mean that with each update on my side I would have to "convert" all my changes "back".

Comment: You should store your Java sources in a directory that contains the "com" directory otherwise no tool will be able to deal with them. This is just part of the way Java works.

Comment: It is not my project, and apparently it works someway, because I have along with sources also binaries.

Answer (score 1):

Easy way out would be right-click on your `src` folder in Eclipse > `New` > `Package` and create a package called `com`. You can then drag all the other packages inside this to fix your problem.

The reason that I asked you about the package names in your `src` folder (*my comment in your question*), was to ascertain how your classes expects the package structure to be. Since they start with `com.bar.foo.`, then in order for them to be compiled by Eclipse.

Comment: Thank you. I believe there is even shorter way -- creating `com` directory under `src`, move everything there and launch Eclipse (Eclipse required to change the names of the dragged copies). However this changes the structure of the project -- I wait for some solution how to convince Eclipse to treat `src` as `src/com`.

Comment: Not so sure if what you're asking is *exactly* possible in Eclipse. But I would be following this post in case a solution comes up. This seems interesting to me! :)